# Syntax highlighting of key = value pairs

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I "inherited" a custom syntax script and I want to update it since it's a little out of date.
The text file for which the syntax highlighting is written contains several blocks like this:

```
{Group1
key1 value1
key2 = value2
key3=value3
#A Comment
}
```

**What's going wrong:**

The problem is, that only `key1 value1` is highlighted correctly, i.e. if an "=" sign is present only the key is highlighted but not the value.
It seems like a trivial problem, but I could not manage to solve it for the last 3h (I should probably mention that this is my first syntax script).

Assuming `key1` is a boolean variable, the corresponding commands in the syntax file are:

```
syn case ignore
syn keyword groupkey key1 nextgroup=group1vars skipwhite
syn match group1vars "true" contained
syn match group1vars "false" contained
syn match groupcomment "#.*$"
syn region groupsection start="{" end="}" contains=groupkey,groupcomment

" Highlighting
hi def link groupcomment Comment
hi def link groupkey Type
hi def link group1vars Constant
```

By the way, I'm pretty sure the guy who was working on it followed [this tutorial](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_your_own_syntax_files).

So I think I understand why it is not working in case a "=" sign is in the same line: `nextgroup=` tells the editor to look for a match after the specified keyword ignoring whitespace due to the `skipwhite`. It works perfectly for `key1 value1`, but as soon as there's an "=" in between no match is found and therefore no highlighting of `value2` and `value3`.

**What I would like to achieve:**

1. Functioning highlighting of values even if there's an
   equal sign present,
2. preferably **no** highlighting of the equal sign itself
3. (optional) solution that's easily applicable for 100+ cases. For some
   of the keys there are 30-50 values to choose from.
   I'd like to avoid two versions for each value (one with and one without 
   equal sign), but if necessary I can always script it.

**What I tried:**

- Creating a specific match for the separator

  ```
  syn match groupsep "=" contained
  ```

  and adding it to `contains=` of the region definition:

  ```
  syn region groupsection start="{" end="}" contains=groupkey,groupcomment,groupsep
  ```

  Unfortunately, that had no effect, so I tried adding the separator match
  to the keyword definition instead

  ```
  syn keyword groupkey key1 nextgroup=group1vars,groupsep skipwhite
  ```

  which also showed no change.
- using `contains=` in the keyword definition

  ```
  syn keyword groupkey key1 contains=group1vars,groupsep
  ```

  which threw me an error (apparently `contains=` cannot be used with
  `syn keyword`).
- using a regular expression for the match, e.g. `"=\=\s*true"`, which
  did work, but also highlighted the equal sign in the same color (see 
  point 2). Also I feel it would be a bit of an overkill if I would have
  to write it in front of every match.

I have a feeling that the solution to my problem would be a nested match, i.e. the editor finds the keyword first, then tries to match `= value` and finally matches `value`, but unfortunately I have no idea how to write that. 
Perhaps even the *keyword-then-match* protocol has to be replaced by using matches only?
Or could it be possible to skip the "=" similar to how it is done with `skipwhite`?
Does someone have an idea what strategy I should use here?

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Are keys and values general? Is it the case that any two non-whitespace strings separated by a space or `=` can be treated as a key-value pair?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by _general_, but yes, the program that reads this text file recognizes any two strings separated by a space or `=` as a key-value pair (given they're in a `{ }` block). In the above example `key1`, `key2` and `key3` would be recognized properly.

Answer (score 2):

This set of syntax rules:

```
syn case ignore
syn region assignment oneline matchgroup=groupkey start=/\k\+\(\s*[[:space:]=]\)\@=/ skip=/\s*=\s*/ matchgroup=groupval end=/\S.*/
syn match groupcomment "#.*$"
syn region groupsection start="{" end="}" contains=assignment,groupcomment

" Highlighting
hi! link groupcomment Comment
hi! link groupkey Type
hi! link groupval Constant
```

Provides this highlighting for me:

[image]

I threw out the existing key/val settings, and used a new match for assignments:

```
syn region assignment oneline matchgroup=groupkey start=/\k\+\(\s*[[:space:]=]\)\@=/ skip=/\s*=\s*/ matchgroup=groupval end=/\S.*/
```

where:

- `groupkey` is used for highlighting the key:

  - which is a string of keyword characters (`\k\+`) followed by
  - at least a space or an `=` (`\s*[[:space:]=]`) with zero-width lookahead (`\@=`), to keep this delimiting space/`=` outside the key.
- any space and `=` in the middle are skipped
- `groupval` highlights the value, which is a non-whitespace character followed by anything.

Comment: So if I understand correctly `matchgroup=groupkey`  is there to map the match (`\k\+`) to `groupkey` and everything after the first non-whitespace character (`\S.*`) is mapped to `groupval`? This already does most of what I would like, but unfortunately wrongly typed values like `Truee` would also be highlighted since no explicit matching is done.

Comment: @CoffeeNerd ah, yes, that's why I asked what the keys and values where. If they're expected to have specific values, then you'll have to list them out in the start and end patterns.

Comment: Oops sry, my bad. So yes, they're expected to have specific values. And to make matters worse, `key1` can adopt any from a list of 100+ values, while `key2` has its own specific list. Differentiating between the two lists is at this point however not my priority. While I'm at it, the comment can also happen to be in the same line as the key-value pair (just at the end though). Thanks for your help by the way!